# Chrome Extension: Запуск скрипта самым первым в контексте страницы

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Мне необходимо реализовать подмену `WebSocket` ([что то похожее на это](https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook/blob/master/wsHook.js)), но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: некоторый скрипт страницы, на которой я хочу сделать подмену `WebSocket`, выполняется раньше моего и делает свою подмену. Возможно странно, ведь в manifest.json я прописал `"run_at": "document_start"`. Внедрение скрипта, который выполняет подмену выглядит так:

```
scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('wrapper.js');
scriptTag.onload = function () { this.remove(); };
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Как заставить браузер выполнить мой внедрённый скрипт гарантированно самым первым?

Comment: Я думаю, если это сторонний домен, то таким образом нельзя получить доступ. Скорее всего на чужой странице будет изолированный API.

Comment: В каком смысле нельзя получить доступ? Код, который я привёл работает, подмена успешна. Проблема лишь в том, что нужно выполниться самым первым на странице.

Comment: _В каком смысле нельзя получить доступ?(с)_. Так код возможно и будет работать, но только в изолированной песочнице, а оттуда получить доступ к стороннему коду нельзя. Скрипт контента имеет доступ, только к изменению DOM. И кстати _...подмена успешна(с)_, для кого успешна? [Сторонний код этой подмены и не заметит.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world) Для перехвата можно использовать debugger

Comment: Вот в чём дело. То есть вообще никак не возможно изменить сообщения вебсокетов на странице с помощью расширения в браузере?

Answer (score 1):

Получить тело ответа и модифицировать через `webRequest`, скорее всего, не получится.
Тут можно посмотреть поддержку [webRequest.filterResponseData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData) и [webRequest.StreamFilter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter).
Несмотря на ограничения, `webRequest` позволяет отслеживать/изменять некоторые заголовки и отменять запросы.

Отправной точкой для получения тела запроса, может быть [debugger](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/).

Небольшой пример (думаю, там можно будет что-то блокировать и менять):

**background.js**

```js
const cRuntime = chrome.runtime
const cTabs = chrome.tabs
const cDebugger = chrome.debugger
const cBrowserAction = chrome.browserAction
const requiredVersion = '1.3'

const tabAttached = new Set()

// Здесь можем просматривать всякие параметры запроса
function onEvent({ tabId }, method, params) {
  // Событий разных много: responseReceived, loadingFinished, loadingFailed и т.п.
  // Для просмотра WebSocket-а достаточно этого
  if (method === 'Network.webSocketFrameReceived') {
    console.log(params.response)
  }
}

// Когда вкладка отключилась от debugger, например закрытие страницы
function onDetach({ tabId }) {
  tabAttached.delete(tabId)
  cDebugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, 'Network.disable', undefined, () => { })
  cDebugger.onDetach.removeListener(onDetach)
  cDebugger.onEvent.removeListener(onEvent)
  console.log('onDetach', tabId)
}

// Присоединяем таб к chrome.debugger
function attach(tabId) {
  if (tabAttached.has(tabId)) {
    return
  }
  cDebugger.attach({ tabId }, requiredVersion, () => {
    if (cRuntime.lastError) {
      console.error(cRuntime.lastError)
      return
    }
    // Активируем прослушивание трафика
    cDebugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, 'Network.enable', undefined, () => {
      if (cRuntime.lastError) {
        console.error(cRuntime.lastError)
        return
      }
      console.log(`Присоединили tabId:${tabId}`)
      tabAttached.add(tabId)
      cDebugger.onDetach.addListener(onDetach)
      cDebugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent)
    })
  })
}

// Используем кнопку расширения для активации прослушивания
cBrowserAction.onClicked.addListener(async (tab) => {
  if (cRuntime.lastError) {
    console.error(cRuntime.lastError)
    return
  }
  if (/^http(s)?.+/.test(tab.url)) {
    attach(tab.id)
  }
})
```

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Demo debugging",
  "description": "Demo debugging",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Alexander Lonberg",
  "browser_action": {},
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "debugger"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background-live-reload.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Расширение активирует прослушивание трафика страницы иконкой самого расширения.
Ищем любой сайт с запросами WebSocket-а, например такой *ruТОЧКАtradingviewТОЧКАcom*.
Открываем график и фоновую страницу DevTools расширения - смотрим в консоль.

Но у такого способа есть небольшой недостаток - оно указывает юзеру, что кто-то подключился к DevTools.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]